# How to get properties of Contact Form 7 object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object, contact-form-7

I'm trying to manipulate some of the mark-up for a contact form on my site, and have managed to get the specific object I want using

```
        $forms = WPCF7_ContactForm::find(array('p' => $redirect['form']));
```

I have no idea what the 'p' key is or why it works, but nothing else seems to.

It returns this object:

```
object(WPCF7_ContactForm)#6114 (9) { ["id":"WPCF7_ContactForm":private]=> int(383) 
["name":"WPCF7_ContactForm":private]=> string(8) "untitled" 
["title":"WPCF7_ContactForm":private]=> string(15) "Customer Survey" 
["locale":"WPCF7_ContactForm":private]=> string(5) "en_GB" 
["properties":"WPCF7_ContactForm":private]=> array(5) { ["form"]=> string(2119) " (really long 
form string) "
```

The form string is the part i want to manipulate to add HTML to it. I do know you can add things like ID's and classes in the editor but that isn't what I'm after. My understanding of objects or arrays within objects has me stumped of just how to access the values here.

Comment: The `properties` property is private, so you can't access it directly; you need to use the getter and setter method the WPCF7_ContactForm class provides.

Comment: Awesome info thank you! So something like: $props = $form->get_properties();
        $props['form'] .=  $manipulations;
                      $form->set_properties($props);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The form string is the part i want to manipulate to add HTML to it.

much easier to do it at the DB level.  The CF7 form stores its meta-data and HTML form as a custom post type wpcf7_contact_form along with a number of meta fields.

The `form` string you're after can be retrieved from the post meta-field table using the form id,

```
$form = get_post_meta($form_id, '_form', true);
```

Comment: Ah I see, I've been mining the wrong ore so to speak. I started down this route because I assumed there would be some kind of hook support but later realised there wasn't.